# dialogflow Raw API response 500 internal server error

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have added intent through Dialogflow(v2) PHP API https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/manage-intents, and i am able to see them on dialogflow console as well. but when i try to search with added intent DF shows "Internal Server Error", while looking at  "Diagnostic Info" show below error:

```
{   "id": "d60722ee-6060-41ac-8984-884e471c77d3",   "timestamp": "2020-01-27T08:51:44.575Z",   "lang": "en",   "status": {
    "code": 500,
    "errorType": "internal_server_error",
    "errorDetails": "Internal Server Error",
    "errorID": "2def8f3a-c0f1-46bb-b23e-8746b8839164"   },   "result": {} }
```

Is this related to DF or something else please help!

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose what it happening without more information. Can you update your question to show the code you used to create the Intent, a screen shot of the Intent showing how it is configured, and how you're testing the Intent?

Answer (score 0):

I Got the solutions on dialogflow docs: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/training

After adding any question on DF via API or DF we need train Agent.

Caution: For agents with more than 780 intents, you need to update the machine learning algorithm manually. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click on the gear icon for your agent.
2. Click the ML Settings tab.
3. Click Train.